# Generate floor map from Active Directory

Tags: c#, sharepoint, active-directory, maps, web-parts

This is probably not possible, but I would like to create an interactive floor map where the offices are static but the person name keeps changing. The information must come from Active Directory, and the map must be displayed on SharePoint.

Is this possible? What do you suggest the best approach to solve the problem?
Do we need to develop a full SharePoint webpart? Is there something in the market?

Any input is truly welcomed. 
Thanks You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen something similar with reporting services before but not using active directory as a data source, if you can dump AD to a database or access it similarly reporting services wouldn't be a terrible option. You would just set a jpg of a blank map as a background and place a 'table' with values on each individual desk/office, it was quite time consuming but it ended up working fairly well. And I'm sure MS has some sort of integration between reporting services and sharepoint.